# typescript for redux action returning dispatch function

Tags: typescript, redux

I've got a simple async action creator which returns a function

```
export const addFiles = (files: any) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        files.forEach(f => {
            dispatch(addFile(f));
            dispatch(validateFile(f));
        });
    };
};
```

When using this action with typescript, by calling `store.dispatch(addFiles(files))``

I get the typescript error

```
Argument of type '(dispatch: any, getState: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Action'.
Property 'type' is missing in type '(dispatch: any, getState: any) => void'
```

I'm not using `redux-thunk` but I have tried to copy the signature as

```
export type ThunkAction<R, S, E> = (dispatch: Dispatch<S>, getState: () => S,
extraArgument: E) => R;
```

And then defined my function as

```
export const addFiles <ThunkAction> = (files: any)
```

But I still get the same error. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not a reducer. Reducers accept a state object and return a state object. It's an action creator.

Answer (score 3):

I think it will work if you use `store.dispatch<any>(addFiles(files))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `(store.dispatch as ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, AnyAction>)(addFiles(files))` if you want to avoid type `any`.